# OctoberCMS static page extra image field shows image real size

Tags: css, image, octobercms-backend

I successfully added an extra field in a static page layout. Now I can easily add an image to my static page. If I want to edit the page, the image that is choosen for this page is being presented in his own dimensions. That way I end up with a page that shows a huge image first and underneath that, the content editior appears. Is there a way to resize that image? I tried with CSS (in modules/cms/formwidgets/mediafinder/assets/css/mediafinder.css) with no result at all.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the html structure of the section with the image in and the css you tried?

Comment: I'm sorry that I react this late: Ive accomplished this already